# Calculus II: Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus

[image]

I tried to find the partial derivatives of x and y respect to v but I don't know how to connect it to $w_v(0,0)$??

Comment: The chain rule says \begin{align} w_{v} &= f_{x} x_{v} + f_{y} y_{v} \\ &= 8 \cos v f_{x} + 2 \cos u \cos v f_{y} \end{align} hence \begin{align} w_{v}(0,0) &= 8 \cos (0) f_{x}(x(0,0),y(0,0)) + 2 \cos (0) \cos (0) f_{y}(x(0,0),y(0,0)) \qquad (1)\end{align} For the definitions of $x$ and $y$, we have \begin{align} x(0,0) &= 5 \\ y(0,0) &= 0 \end{align} so substituting into $(1)$ gives \begin{align} w_{v}(0,0) &= 8 f_{x}(5,0) + 2 f_{y}(5,0) \\ &= 8(5) + 2(5) \\ &= 50 \end{align}

Comment: You should start by computing $w_v$. Please use latex code like this:  w_v(u,v)=f_x(x(u,v),y(u,v))x_v(u,v)+f_y(x(u,v),y(u,v))y_v(u,v).  Use dollar signs to turn the code into real symbols.